# Condition in linq select

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, join

i have an inner linq join between 2 table which would look something like below :

```
(from A in table1 join B in table2 
on   A.name equals B.name 
where {some condition}
select new { 
A.name ,
A.color,
.
.
.
}).toList();
```

the problem is that in some records *"name"* is *null* and i want the linq query replace *null* with " " in select part.

something like this :

```
select new {
A.name!=null?A.name : " "
.
.
.
}
```

how can i do this ?

(i know that i can have acondition in *where* i check to not be *null* but in that case it will skip that record but i want to take it and replace the *null* name with a string )

thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# LINQ replacing nulls with meaningful string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838232/c-sharp-linq-replacing-nulls-with-meaningful-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [null-coalescing operator `??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) with an empty string as default value. Then assign its result to a property in anonymous type

```cs
select new { 
    name = A.name ?? "",
    //rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/92R3jW)

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Student collection
        IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
                new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = null, Age = 13} ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Moin",  Age = 21 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 18 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20} ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 15 } 
            };

        // LINQ Query Syntax to find out teenager students
        var teenAgerStudent = (from s in studentList
                              where s.Age > 12 && s.Age < 20
                              select new {Name=s.StudentName??"Tuna"}).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("Teen age Students:");

        foreach(var std in teenAgerStudent){            
            Console.WriteLine(std.Name);
        }
    }
}

public class Student{

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```